# React Native - Xcode Build Using Bad Environment Variabled

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native

I am building a react-native project using "sudo react-native run-ios" command. The build environment variables are acting weird, not returning the expected values such as /Users/userName for $HOME. Instead, I'm getting the following values:

for $USER_LIBRARY_DIR - will result: `/var/root/Library`

for $HOME - will result `/var/root`

this is happening ONLY when I build the react project. The Xcode project is compiling smoothly.

Why don't the environment variables return the correct value? I am using a secondary (admin) user on my macbook pro. Might that be related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sudo` will make the command run as root, skip the `sudo` part, delete any build intermediaries and you should be fine.